# Is ultrafilter convolution a special case of convolution of probability measures?

Tags: measure-theory, semigroups, filters

If $G$ is a semigroup and $\beta G$ is the set of ultrafilters on $G$, then $\beta G$ is also a semigroup: given $p,q\in \beta G$, we define
$$p*q := \{E\subseteq G : \{g\in G : g^{-1}A\in q\}\in p\}.$$
This is a strange definition at first, but indeed it is an associative binary operation on $\beta G$, and we have an embedding of semigroups $G\hookrightarrow \beta G$ by identifying each element of $G$ with its point-mass.

An ultrafilter $p$ can be identified with its indicator function $\chi_p:\mathcal{P}(G)\rightarrow \{0,1\}$, where $\mathcal{P}(G)$ is the power set of $G$. This is a finitely-additive probability measure on $G$.

Thus let $\mathrm{Pr}^0(G)$ be the space of all finitely-additive probability measures $\mu:\mathcal{P}(G)\rightarrow [0,1]$, so that $\beta G\subseteq \mathrm{Pr}^0(G)$. (Note that we consider every subset of $G$ to be measurable.) Given two probability measures $\mu,\nu\in \mathrm{Pr}^0(G)$, we should be able to *convolve* them as follows:

1. Construct the *product* probability measure $\mu\times \nu$, determined uniquely by the requirement that $(\mu\times\nu)(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$ for all $A,B\subseteq G$.
2. Let the convolution $\mu*\nu$ be the pushforward of $\mu\times \nu$ via the multiplication map $G\times G\rightarrow G$. Thus $$(\mu*\nu)(E) := (\mu\times \nu)\left(\{(x,y)\in G\times G: xy\in E\}\right).$$

Is this correct? This should be an associative binary operation on $\mathrm{Pr}^0(G)$, making it into a semigroup.

Viewing $\beta G$ as a subset of $\mathrm{Pr}^0(G)$ by $p\mapsto \chi_p$, we can ask: is ultrafilter convolution the same as convolution of the corresponding probability measures?

> **Question:** Does $p\mapsto \chi_p$ define a semigroup homomorphism $\beta G \rightarrow \mathrm{Pr}^0(G)$?

Comment: You have defined $\mu\times\nu$ only on sets of the form $A\times B$.  There is no reason to expect this to extend uniquely to all subsets of $G\times G$.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that there is *no* reason --- it is indeed true for countably-additive probability measures. Does it fail if we replace "countably-additive" with "finitely-additive"?

Comment: No, even then you can only extend to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by rectangles.

Comment: It is reasonable to expect your definition $\mu\times\nu$ to extend to a unique finitely additive probability measure on _some_ algebra of subsets of $G\times G$.  But there is no reason that algebra would contain the sets $\{(x,y)\in G\times G:xy\in E\}$ you need to define $\mu*\nu$.

Comment: In the case of commutative $G$, your convolution, if it exists, would also be commutative (just by inspection of the definition). But that's not the case for the product of ultrafilters.